# Python MySQL cursor fails to fetch rows

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to fetch data from AWS MariaDB:

```
cursor = self._cnx.cursor()
stmt = ('SELECT * FROM flights')

cursor.execute(stmt)

print(cursor.rowcount)
# prints 2

for z in cursor:
    print(z)
# Does not iterate

row = cursor.fetchone()
# row is None

rows = cursor.fetchall()
# throws 'No result set to fetch from.'
```

I can verify that table contains data using MySQL Workbench. Am I missing some step?

EDIT: re 2 answers:

```
res = cursor.execute(stmt)
# res is None
```

EDIT:

I created new Python project with a single file:

```
import mysql.connector

try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='foobar.rds.amazonaws.com',
        user='devuser',
        password='devpasswd',
        database='devdb'
    )

    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    #cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)

    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM flights')

    print(cursor.rowcount)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
```

If I run this code with simple cursor, fetchall raises "No result set to fetch from". If I run with buffered cursor, I can see that _rows property of cursor contains my data, but fetchall() returns empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `cursor.execute(stmt)` returns an object with results and you're not storing that.

`results = cursor.execute(stmt)
print(results.fetchone()) # Prints out and pops first row`

Comment: execute resturns None, so this throws exception about calling method on the None type

Comment: Hmmm...
I think I found some details on what your cursor is possibly returning.
Maybe it's not setup correctly?
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-cursor.html

Answer (score 0):

For the future googlers with the same Problem I found a workaround which may help in some cases:

I didn't find the source of the problem but a solution which worked for me.

In my case .fetchone() also returned none whatever I did on my local(on my own Computer) Database. I tried the exact same code with the Database on our companies server and somehow it worked. So I copied the complete server Database onto my local Database (by using database dumps) just to get the server settings and afterwards I also could get data from my local SQL-Server with the code which didn't work before.

I am a SQL-newbie but maybe some crazy setting on my local SQL-Server prevented me from fetching data. Maybe some more experienced SQL-user knows this setting and can explain.